# How to choose the best dissimilarity method?

Tags: clustering, distance-functions

There are a lot of methods to measure the distance between pairs of objects such as Euclidean distance, Standardized Euclidean distance, Minkowski, Cosine distance and Correlation distance,.... etc 
Is choosing the method depend on the data type? 
What is the best criteria should i follow to select the best method?

Comment: If it only were that easy. Sometimes it is a matter of what you want to do, sometimes of what your data looks like.